# Having Trouble logging into Ask Ubuntu on my phone

Tags: discussion, android

I have been trying to login to Ask Ubuntu on my phone and I keep getting this message. How can I fix this so I can login to this site from my phone. The browser I am using is google chrome, the os my phone is using is Android 4.1.2 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here's your problem (and the solution!):

You have the new "bandwidth saving"in chrome turned on.

You need to turn it off - head to the settings, then bandwith savings, then turn it off.

Try to login - it should let you.

Once you're logged in, you can turn it back on.

Technical guess of what is going on here: Stack Exchange is seeing a lot of login requests for different users coming from the same IP address. So, all of us chrome on android users have triggered the Stack Exchange Haxxor defense system.